# Swift func that takes a Metatype?

Tags: ios, swift

As Apple says in the [**Metatype Type**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1027) section in Swift's docs:

> A metatype type refers to the type of any type, including class types, structure types, enumeration types, and protocol types.

Is there a base class to refer to any class, struct, enum, or protocol (eg **MetaType**)?

My understanding is that protocol types are limited to use as a generic constraint, because of Self or associated type requirements (well, this is what an Xcode error was telling me).

So, with that in mind, maybe there is a **Class** base class for identifying class references? Or a **Type** base class for all constructable types (class, struct, enum)? Other possibilities could be **Protocol**, **Struct**, **Enum**, and **Closure**.

See this example if you don't get what I mean yet.

```
func funcWithType (type: Type) {
  // I could store this Type reference in an ivar,
  // as an associated type on a per-instance level.
  // (if this func was in a class, of course)
  self.instanceType = type
}

funcWithType(String.self)
funcWithType(CGRect.self)
```

While generics work great with 1-2 constant associated types, I wouldn't mind being able to treat associated types as instance variables.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `AnyObject` refers to anything that is a class, I believe.

Comment: Right, but I can't use `AnyObject.Type` to accept any class metatype (`String.Type`, `UIView.Type`, `CGRect.Type`, etc).

Comment: In other words, I'm trying to work with types, not instances.

Comment: How about `AnyClass`?

Comment: @aleclarson: `AnyClass` is just a type alias for `AnyObject.Type`

Answer (score 13):

This works:

```
func funcWithType (type: Any.Type) {
}

funcWithType(String.self)
funcWithType(CGRect.self)
```

Comment: What does `Any` semantically mean, when it is `protocol<>`? Everything that is or has a protocol... ;-( ?

Comment: @ViktorLexington: The `protocol<...>` syntax allows you to specify multiple protocols, and denotes the intersection of those protocols. The set of types that conform to `protocol<Protocol1, Protocol2>` is the intersection of the set of types that conform to `Protocol1` and the set of types that conform to `Protocol2`. Therefore, `protocol<>` is the intersection of 0 protocols. The identity of the set intersection operation is the universe of elements. So the set of types that conform to `protocol<>` is all (non-function) types.

Comment: I’d suggest using generics: `func funcWithType<T>(x: T.Type) { … }`

Comment: @RobRix: is there any case you can think of where that would work and mine wouldn't?

Answer (score 2):

Given your example an implementation would be:

```
// protocol that requires an initializer so you can later call init from the type
protocol Initializeable {
    init()
}

func funcWithType (type: Initializeable.Type) {
    // make a new instance of the type
    let instanceType = type()
    // in Swift 2 you have to explicitly call the initializer:
    let instanceType = type.init()

    // in addition you can call any static method or variable of the type (in this case nothing because Initializeable doesn't declare any)
}

// make String and CGRect conform to the protocol
extension String: Initializeable {}
extension CGRect: Initializeable {}

funcWithType(String.self)
funcWithType(CGRect.self)
```